# javascript tooltip follows cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a tooltip with an image appear above the cursor when hovering over a thumbnail, but I'm working with another developer's code and having trouble figuring it out.

I've created a simplified version of the code on the website which can be found below, or on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justinwebpro/kf8Lqn5v/5/

or a live site with the issue I'm trying to correct here: https://www.mychicnest.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=503

I'm trying to use the method .mousemove() to make it follow the mouse position rather than being static at the top of the page but I'm doing something wrong. Ideally it would factor in an offset of the cursor position, but getting it to work at all comes first!

**HTML**

```
<div id="swatch">
    <div id="panel">  
        <img src="large.jpg" id="large-image" />
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="1.jpg" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <img src="3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#swatch { position: relative; }

#panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: -115px;
        left: 115px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function swThumbEffect(){
    $('#panel').css('visibility','hidden');

    $('#thumbs img').mouseover(function(){
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        $('#panel').css('visibility','visible');
    });
    $('#thumbs img').mouseout(function(){
        $('#panel').css('visibility','hidden');
    });
}


// This is what I came up with to get the swatch to follow the cursor but it isn't working as I hoped. Ideally it would factor in an offset of the cursor, but getting it to work comes first.
$('#thumbs img').mousemove(function( event ) {
    var mousePositionX = event.pageX;
    var mousePositionY = event.pageY;
    log(mousePositionX);
    log(mousePositionY);
    $('#panel').css('left', mousePositionX);
    $('#panel').css('right', mousePositionY);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When `swThumbEffect()` called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with you current function, but it should work with minor modifications. First problem: you're setting `right` css property to `clientY`. It should be `top`:

```
     $('#panel').css('top', mousePositionY);
```

Then you need to consider position of `#panel` parent to position it correctly. You can do it this way:

```
     //You should avoid showing the panel right under the mouse, because it'll mess
     //with your mouseout event since the #thumb will be hidden.
     //You can add 20 pixels to the position for example.  
     var mousePositionX = event.pageX-$('#panel').parent().offset().left+20;
     var mousePositionY = event.pageY-$('#panel').parent().offset().top+20;
```

And maybe you should try to put the `mousemove` call in your `swThumbEffect` function with other `mouseevents` call.

And normally it should work properly.

Comment: Good catch on 'top'. I completely overlooked that. I also noticed I used log() rather than console.log() as well, whoops! Once I changed those out and made the adjustment for the offset it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

every time `mousemove` fires, (5-10 times in second)
you must update your element position.

This is the code i wrote the other day:

http://jsfiddle.net/y5ua8n9f/

If I will have time later, i will update here.

Best of luck!